# CKQuery where predicate has reference and not field?

Tags: cloudkit, ckquery

I need to create a `CKQuery` where the predicate **contains a reference** of a record, and not a field of the record.

Like this

```
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "OUP", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "o = %@", "FF4FB4A9-271A-4AF4-B02C-722ABF25BF44")
```

How do I set `o` is a CKReference, not field!

I get this error:

*Field value type mismatch in query predicate for field 'o'*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found in [CKQuery class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/index.html) the answer, or at least an example how to use `CKReference` in `CKQuery`:

```
CKReference* recordToMatch = [[CKReference alloc] initWithRecordID:employeeID action:CKReferenceActionNone];
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"employee == %@", recordToMatch];
```

To match records that link to a different record whose ID you know, create a predicate that matches a field containing a reference object as shown in Listing 1. In the example, the employee field of the record contains a CKReference object that points to another record. When the query executes, a match occurs when the ID in the locally created CKReference object is the same ID found in the specified field of the record.

Answer (score 15):

You can use a **CKRecord** or **CKRecordID**, with or without a **CKReference**, to match relationships.

CKRecord:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "artist == %@", artist)
```

CKRecordID:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "artist == %@", artistID)
```

CKReference with CKRecord:

```
let recordToMatch = CKReference(record: artist, action: CKReferenceAction.None)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "artist == %@", recordToMatch)
```

CKReference with CKRecordID:

```
let recordToMatch = CKReference(recordID: artistID, action: CKReferenceAction.None)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "artist == %@", recordToMatch)
```